# grub menu appearing after 10 minutes and it's responding very slow

Tags: boot, 16.04, dual-boot, grub2

currently I'm using dual booted ubuntu 16.04 LTS along with windows 8.1 in my hp15r204tx laptop and it was running great. But suddenly grub is appearing after long time in startup and grub menu is very laggy and responding slow when I'm moving my arrow keys to select any option.
My etc/fstab file looks like this

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda11 during installation
UUID=dbfa8dc7-3265-4f19-85ef-584294eed2fe /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=207F-463D  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda10 during installation
#UUID=070ab5c2-2c28-4e86-baae-3d3900bfeeac none            swap    sw              0       0
```

This is the output of systemd-analyze blame

```
3min 392ms powerd.service
         46.608s apt-daily.service
         27.123s nmbd.service
         26.906s samba-ad-dc.service
         17.650s click-system-hooks.service
         12.655s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
          9.660s systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-207F\x2d463D.service
          7.996s rstudio-server.service
          7.352s dev-sda10.device
          6.854s NetworkManager.service
          6.377s ModemManager.service
          4.877s accounts-daemon.service
          3.526s qemu-kvm.service
          3.511s gpu-manager.service
          3.058s ofono.service
          2.913s grub-common.service
          2.904s thermald.service
          2.268s apparmor.service
          1.880s plymouth-start.service
          1.875s polkitd.service
          1.725s systemd-user-sessions.service
          1.564s systemd-rfkill.service
          1.487s irqbalance.service
          1.423s binfmt-support.service
          1.388s lightdm.service
          1.386s systemd-udevd.service
          1.313s keyboard-setup.service
          1.299s setvtrgb.service
          1.289s apport.service
          1.231s rsyslog.service
          1.183s user@1002.service
          1.171s systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
          1.171s ssh.service
          1.164s systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
          1.092s bluetooth.service
           987ms upower.service
           905ms ondemand.service
           895ms wpa_supplicant.service
           864ms systemd-logind.service
           789ms systemd-journald.service
           678ms networking.service
           661ms sys-kernel-debug.mount
           651ms dev-hugepages.mount
           648ms dev-mqueue.mount
           633ms systemd-modules-load.service
           603ms avahi-daemon.service
           536ms console-setup.service
           515ms user@1000.service
           504ms colord.service
           398ms nvidia-persistenced.service
           363ms pppd-dns.service
           362ms systemd-sysctl.service
           352ms systemd-timesyncd.service
           324ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
           324ms dev-sda11.swap
           306ms smbd.service
           297ms speech-dispatcher.service
           285ms kmod-static-nodes.service
           280ms rc-local.service
           274ms ufw.service
           225ms udisks2.service
           218ms systemd-remount-fs.service
           210ms systemd-journal-flush.service
           183ms alsa-restore.service
           177ms plymouth-read-write.service
           157ms systemd-random-seed.service
           145ms systemd-update-utmp.service
           130ms dns-clean.service
           128ms rtkit-daemon.service
           119ms openvpn.service
           111ms boot-efi.mount
           100ms systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service
            49ms proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.mount
            17ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
            16ms systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service
             6ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service
             5ms ureadahead-stop.service
             4ms resolvconf.service
             2ms plymouth-quit-wait.service
```

And this is the content of my /etc/default/grub file

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash usbcore.old_scheme_first=1"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=1280x800

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

Answer (score 0):

To check the file system on your Ubuntu partition...

- boot to the GRUB menu
- choose Advanced Options
- choose Recovery mode
- choose Root access
- at the # prompt, type `sudo fsck -f /`
- repeat the fsck command if there were errors
- type `reboot`